# How to execute a server command using php?

Tags: php

I have some programs installed at the server side of my LAN . 
I want the client to be able to execute the server function for instance "svn --help"
using command line ..
My server url for eg xx.xxx.x.xxx
I know that passthru() is the function i have to use . 
How can I make my client to communicate with the server using command line to execute this command ?

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
$result = `svn --help`;
echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: @vimalBasdeo note backticks ` are not the same as '